# Set subsection (Level 3) indentation to 0.5 inches from left margin

Tags: sectioning, indentation, thesis, article

I am using the following class to type my thesis:
https://interval.louisiana.edu/thesis-class/ULL-thesis-class-explanation.html
What edits should I make to the class to fix the indentation problem? In addition, I would like to add indentation of 0.5 inches from left margin in the abstract and biosketch page. \indent, \hspace{0.5in}, and \hspace*{0.5} didn't work out. \qquad and \quad did work but I can't set the indentation to 0.5 inches. How can I fix this issue in the class?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{ullthesis2017}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.25in}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/} }
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage[intoc,refpage]{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\renewcommand{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}}
%\newcommand{\nm}[2]{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{epsfig} %% for loading postscript figures
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{mydef}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
%\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,firstinits=true,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\vspace*{20pt}} %add space between bibliography title and first entry
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}
\addbibresource{mendeley.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Nomenclature %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[intoc, english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%landscape table %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{everypage}
%\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\ifdim\textwidth=\linewidth\else\bgroup
%  \dimendef\margin=0 %use \margin instead of \dimen0
%  \ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
%  \else\margin=\evensidemargin
%  \fi
%  \raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-0.5\linewidth}[0pt][0pt]{%
%    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}%
%    \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}%
%\egroup\fi}
%\AddEverypageHook{\Lpagenumber}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\singlespacing\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: \ }{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{-0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}  

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries}{\thesection\ }{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*0}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\subsection}
{\parindent}{*0}{0pt}% 0pt before edit


\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\itshape\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[.]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
{\parindent}{*0}{0pt}% 0pt before edit


\usepackage{tocloft} \setlength{\cftsecindent}{0.5in} \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{1in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\raggedright  % Changed from raggedright (my edit)
%\parindent=0.5in
%\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in} % for making paragraph indent 0.5 inches edited by me
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}

\begin{document}
    \title{A Comprehensive }
    \author{Ab}
    \convocationdate{Summer}
    \gradyear{2018}
    \degree{Masters in Science}
    \major{Engineering}
    \supervisor{Ab}
   \ranksupervisor{Associate Professor }
        \deanofgraduateschool{M}
    \firstcommitteemember{F}
  \rankfirstcommitteemember{Professor }
    \secondcommitteemember{Me}
  \ranksecondcommitteemember{Assistant }
  \filefordedication{B-dedicatory}
  \fileforacknowledgement{B-acknowledgement}
   \prefatorypages   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \include{C-chapter1}
    \include{C-chapter2}
    \include{C-chapter3}
    \include{C-chapter4}
    \include{C-chapter5}
    \include{C-chapter6}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliography{mendeley}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
\appendix
\closingpages
    \include{F-abstract}
    \include{F-biosketch}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only a guess: Change `\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{*0}{0pt}` to `\titlespacing{\subsection}{.5in}{*0}{0pt}`.

Comment: @esdd your suggestion fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

You are using `\titlespacing` provided by package `titlesec`. The second argument of this command sets the indentation for the `runin` heading level in the first argument. So you have to replace your `\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{*0}{0pt}` by

```
\titlespacing{\subsection}{.5in}{*0}{0pt}
```